# How can I create a new Main Window?

Tags: c#, macos, duplicates, nswindow, xamarin.mac

I am writing a Xamarin macOs C# app, and want to "duplicate" the main window (i.e. create a new identical window) - I thought I'd create a new instance of the current main window, but nothing I tried seems to work (the window doesn't open) and the documentation/forums/Q&A websites weren't much help.
*(Please note that i want to duplicate the main window, so all the contents and behaviors should remain the same)*

I tried re-instancing the main window's controller and spawning it that way, but that just did nothing:

```
// Create a new instance of the window controller
var windowController = new MainWindowController();
// Initialize the new window
windowController.Init();
windowController.Load();
// Make the new window the key window
windowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

I tried getting a new storyboard and instancing it from there, but still nothing:

```
// Get the main storyboard
var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName("main_storyboard", null);
// Get the window controller
var windowController = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as NSWindowController;
// Focus the window and bring it on top
windowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```

I am kind of new to Xamarin, so sorry if I missed something-

Comment: Is it possible that you need the document-based app (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Designing/Designing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH2-SW3)? In this model you have the dedicated "main" window for the each opened document and some stuff the manage all of this

Comment: @Serg i am writing xamarin

Comment: Xamarin fully supports document-based applications and includes all the necessary bindings. So, if your use cases fit the doc-based look and feel, then you can consider going that route, even with Xamarin or modern net core/macos SDK (but I can't say anything about the xamarin forms or maui thought)

Comment: i'll consider it, tho i am looking to create a new instance of the main window, not a new main window for each document

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried duplicating the MainWindow. But I have other windows. Some from storyboards, some from Xib and some created completely programaticaly. In some cases it is required to call ShowWindow():

```
windowController.ShowWindow(null);
windowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);
```